# Can i connect 14-2 wire to the current 12-2 wire in this case?

Tags: wire

i have already had 12-2 wire running through my garage. Now i have a small shed which is 50 feet away from the garage. My plan is to dismantle one of the outlet in the garage which is where the 12-2 wire ends. From there, i will:

- Install a switch at the old outlet place (That switch will play a role as a circuit breaker for the whole shed)
- Start connecting my 14-2 wire to my shed.
- In the shed there would be only 1 more outlet which i use mostly for charging tools.

The reason i use 14-2 wire is because I have a 100ft of 14-2 wire UF from my friend and i do not want to waste it.

Just wonder, is that OK to do as above? Please advise, thanks a lot.

Comment: If I understand you will feed the switch with  the original 12-2.Then interrupt the circuit with a wall switch. Then continue the run with 14-2 to supply the shed?

Comment: 50' of 12ga 12-2 direct bury wire will be about $30 (the 14ga wire you have is rated for direct bury, right?).  If you us the 14ga wire, you'll have to downgrade the breaker to a 15A at a cost of about $4.  So it will cost you an extra $26 to run the 12ga.  Considering the work to bury  & install 50' of wire, this seems trivial.  And you'll have a little more power out there if you ever decide to do something more out in that shed.

Comment: And a 50 ft run of 14 gauge wire with a 15 amp load results in a 3.16% voltage drop, just over the limit of 3%.

Comment: thank @bib, then what should be the ideal plan in this case? Selling the 14-2 wire and purchase another 12-2? Thanks

Comment: Most subpanels use dreally big wires, and that is sort of what you are running (even though it is *very* small). I would opt for the 12/2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is fine.  Whichever circuit breaker feeds that entire circuit, **must be replaced with a 15A breaker**.  The presence of any 14AWG wire anywhere in the circuit requires the breaker be 15A.

I don't know what you had in mind with the switch, but switches are not circuit breakers.

If you plan to use a full 15A in the shed, a common $1 switch will not handle that, you'd need to upgrade to a $7ish heavy duty switch.

Comment: Well.. it's  quite **not fine** unless  you downgrade the breaker!  The OP might want to compare the cost of a breaker vs. the delta cost of 14 vs 12 gauge wire run to the shed.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft i apologize for being unclear.  I have edited to **bold** relevant text.  I agree that cost delta 14 vs 12 is probably less than the breaker, however OP already possesses the 14AWG UF cable.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like an ideal plan. As a newbie to DIY, i was thinking about using a common $1 which you were talking about to be the switch for the whole shed. But will the heavy duty switch good enough for handle the on/off for the whole shed? Thanks